# refering to a calculated variable in a hiveql query

Tags: sql, hive, sas, hiveql

I am coming to hive from sas proc sql.  In sas you can use a variable that you calculated in the same query that you calculated it by using the word calculated.

Is there a way to do this in hiveql or do you have to calculate the variable in one query and add it to a table/data set and then use it in another query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `calculated` keywords is a `proc sql` extension, not available in other databases.  The typical methods are a CTE or subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select . . ., . . . as new_column
      from . . .
     )
select t.*, <new_column expression>
from cte;
```

Or something similar with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

All the `calculated` keyword in SAS does is allow you to reference a variable you defined earlier in the select clause without re-typing the code that derived it.  In other SQL dialects you just have to repeat the logic again.

So instead of code like this to reference the value of BMI

```
select gender
     , wt/ht**2 as bmi
     , case when (calculated bmi > 30) then 1 else 0 end as obese
from have
```

You just need to re-calculate BMI.

```
select gender
     , wt/ht**2 as bmi
     , case when ((wt/ht**2) > 30) then 1 else 0 end as obese
from have
```

Comment: Would this work if bmi was calculated in a case statement? Can you embed a case statement in another case statement?